# Using serial port with stty not working, minicom ok

Tags: linux, serial-port, stty

I'm trying to write to a serial port and read results via bash scrpts (echo, printf, and read).   I've setup stty correctly as far as I can workout, but I can't read any characters back.

If I place port in loopback, I can use minicom to send and receive characters ok.  yay :)

but when I quit minicom, and echo some chars to the device, the seial port flashes rx led once, and reading doesn't not show any characters.  Further echo commands do NOT cause the rx led to flash, so it seems I can only send once.

Any ideas what could be going on and how I can get things working.

Thanks, Brendan.

Comment: I think it has something to do with running the commands from the bash prompt.  If I put in a script then I at least get 1 character back.  I echo "ABCD" and I get the char 'B' back and that's it.  Not sure why I get the second char back and not the first.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar problem. If I run "minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 4800" it sits there with a blank screen until I run "stty -F /dev/ttyUSB0 raw ispeed 4800" then data starts streaming in.  Then if I quit minicom and "cat /dev/ttyUSB0" it works fine. However if unplug and and replug and start with "cat /dev/ttyUSB0" I get nothing even if I run stty. Anyone got any ideas???